# How to implement two methods one from each interfaces which contain more method definition?

Tags: c#, oop

```
interface Ia 
{
    void m1();
    void m2();
}

interface Ib
{
    void m3();
    void m4();
}
```

Here how to implement m1, and m3 in a class?

Comment: You have to implement them all. If I say I am a `Ia` and `Ib` then I must be able to do all four of them (or I am lying - which the compiler will understandably complain about). _Also, these kinds of problems are way easier to discuss if you use meaningful interface and method names._

Comment: What have you tried, and in what way did it fail?

Comment: You can't pick and choose which interface members you want to implement. The implementing type must provide an implementation for all the interface's members (even if the type is abstract it must provide an abstract member at the very least). An interface is similar to a contract, if the code could choose what parts of the contract it wanted to implement it would no longer be a valid contract.

Comment: You should split them into multiple interfaces if you only use one. You could implement both and throw a `NotSupportedException()` but this is bad programming practice as it goes against SOLID principles.

Comment: An interface is a CONTRACT, you must implement all methods in the interface.  An interface is a way to implement polymorphism.  more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a class which inherits from both interfaces - in that case you also need to implment `m2()` and `m4()` beside `m1()` and `m3()`.

```
interface Ia
{
    void m1();
    void m2();
}

interface Ib
{
    void m3();
    void m4();
}


public class Ca : Ia , Ib
{
    public void m1() { }
    public void m2() { throw new NotImplementedException();  }
    public void m3() { }
    public void m4() { throw new NotImplementedException();  }
}
```

You can't just pick some methods from the interface to be part of your class - they all have to be implemented. I would change the architecture of you interfaces or if you can't acces this code, you can implement them with a `NotImplementedException()`

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, you can, but you shouldn't do this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Comment: @NibblyPig right, that isn't good practice and should be considered as the last way out. Anyway I would use the `NotImplementedException` instead of `NotSupportedException`

Comment: `NotSupportedException` is preferred in this case, `You might choose to throw a NotImplementedException exception in properties or methods in your own types when the that member is still in development and will only later be implemented in production code. In other words, a NotImplementedException exception should be synonymous with "still in development."` and `Throw a NotSupportedException exception if the implementation of an interface member or an override to an abstract base class method is not possible. ` from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notimplementedexception

Answer (score 0):

You can't handpick what member to implement, **you must implement every interface member**. If you need fine grained control over what interface member you want to implement then you should apply the [interface segregation principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and interface inheritance to customize them to your need, for example:

```
interface Isa
{
    void m1();
}

interface Isb
{
    void m3();
}

interface Ia : Isa
{
    void m2();
}

interface Ib : Isb
{
    void m4();
}

class C1 : Isa, Isb
{
   public void m1() { }
   public void m3() { }
}
```

This way,  you achieve exactly what you want and maintain the structure of interfaces `Ia` and `Ib`. Keep in mind that this is an example and blindly applying segregation and inheritance quickly becomes a software design anti-pattern. Its use must be justified and planed for with care.